# Question about manipulation of productories

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, trigonometry

[image]
I'm having trouble understanding this manipulation of products.
what steps should i follow to conclude that $\prod_{j=0}^{2m} \sin(z+j*\pi/n)$ is equal to $(-1)^m \prod_{j=0}^{m}\sin(z+j\pi/n)\prod_{j=m+1}^{2m}\sin(z+j\pi/n-\pi)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two steps within the relevant equality. They first split the product up into $j=0$ to $m$ and $j=m+1$ to $2m$. They leave the former product alone, but for the latter product they then further use $\sin(\theta)=-\sin(\theta-\pi)$ to write $$\prod_{j=m+1}^{2m}\sin(z+j\pi/n)=\prod_{j=m+1}^{2m} (-\sin(z+j\pi/n-\pi))=(-1)^n \prod_{j=m+1}^{2m} \sin(z+j\pi/n-\pi).$$
This yields the desired equality.

Comment: Thank you comrade